# ^[:blank:] does not match dot in sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have an input as follows:

> INa.aa................... October 2010 after its previous U.S.-based owners failed to pay debts

My goal is to put brackets around every word starting with letter `i`/`I`. So I issued a command:

```
sed 's/\<i[^[:blank:]]*\>/(&)/gi' input_data
```

Which returned this output:

> (INa.aa)................... October 2010 after (its) previous U.S.-based owners failed to pay debts

What I don't get is, why doesn't the `^[:blank:]*` also include the dots after `INa.aa`?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the `\>` "end of word" escape. A word boundary is defined as

> the character to the left is a "word" character and the character to the right is a "non-word" character, or vice-versa

in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes) (referring to `\b`). In the case of `\>`, the "vice-versa" does not apply.

What is a "word" character?

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character.

And "non-word" are all the others. You expect the boundary between your periods and a blank to match `\>`, but it doesn't: both the period and the blank are non-word characters. The word boundary is between the last `a` and the first `.`.

The period between the `a`s is also surrounded by word boundaries, but because there aren't any blanks involved, it's a part of the match.

If you want to match everything up to the next blank, you can just skip the `\>` in your regex.

Comment: Very good answer, did not even know I can skip the closing \>. Thanks!